# Mongo DB Secondary Nodes Election

Tags: mongodb

I have a question regarding secondary nodes in mongodb. there are priority 0, delayed, hidden and arbiter.

Which one of these can trigger an election. As per doc priority 0 cannot. What about hidden, delayed and arbiter can they trigger an election?

Is arbiter visible to client?

Answer (score 0):

Arbiter is not visible to client, as its purpose is only for voting when primary goes down.